# Trigger function only once when using visibilitychange and focus event listeners

Tags: javascript

I need to call a function when a window is either focused or becomes visible, so I set the following listeners:

```
window.addEventListener("focus", (event) => {
    SomeFunction();
});

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
  if (document.hidden) {
    // don't do anything for hidden state
  } else {
    // document is visible
    SomeFunction();
  }
});
```

But then when a window is changing to `visible`, it's also considered focused. How can I then make sure I run the function once - if it's changing to visible - then don't trigger the function via the `focus` listener, and only trigger it when it's really focused

Comment: Could you have a variable you set to avoid double-executing? Could `SomeFunction()`handle this?

Comment: Yes, so you mean I should pass the event itself to the function? like `SomeFunction(event)` and then use it inside the function?

Comment: Not necessarily. You just need to make it *idempotent* as in calling it more than once has no effect. This could be as simple as testing a variable on entry, like `if (!already_done) { return }; already_done = true`. It'd require having a variable outside the scope of the function, but there's lots of places you could put those.

Comment: You could have `SomeFunction` be throttled or debounced. It won't resolve the underlying issue, but it should work.

Comment: A more elegant way is to flip a `data` property on whatever you're showing, and if that's already set you can skip calling `SomeFunction()`.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's not OOP it's simply an XHR call to the backend to extend the user's session in case he comes back so he won't be disconnected for being idle. In this case I think I should do some limit. Because even if I use the flag option with `already_done` it might not work as expected, since I need to be able to re-use it again even after doing it. But, I can combine it with rate limit and add some timeout. So I think the combination of your comments will solve it

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `event` reference to the callback and check the event's type in that function:

```js
addEventListener("focus", (event) => {
    SomeFunction(event);
});

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
    SomeFunction(event);
});

function SomeFunction(e) {
   // Check wich event got you here and only respond to one of them
   if(e.type === "focus"){
     console.log("focus");
   } else if(e.type === "visibilitychange") {
     console.log("visibilitychange");
   }
}
```

Comment: There's a typo in `someFunction`. Parameter name should be `event`

Comment: This still doesn't work, `visibilitychange` triggers both `focus` and `visibilitychange` if the mouse was previously inside the document (Click inside the snippet, then change tab and come back)

Comment: @Stackerito I think you miss the point of the code. Within the if/else if branches you can do whatever you like, including cancelling the event or removing the other event handler. This code gives you the ability to handle either event in any way you want.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the problem was that when I wasn't using both listeners I had some trouble with knowing when a user comes back to the page. Because it wouldn't always trigger for only one of them. Now when using both, it will always be triggered when a user comes back, and I need to run the function when a user returns to the page so I can't tell from which event it happens and cancel the event